# About independence of sentences from a given set of axioms

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

> Assume $\text{Sat }\Phi $. $\phi$ is independent of $\Phi $ iff $\text{not Sat } \Phi \cup \{\phi\}$ and $\text{not Sat } \Phi \cup \{\neg \phi\}$.

Above definitely doesn't make sense as taking any model $\mathfrak{A} $ of $\Phi$, $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A})$ is complete thus either $\text{Sat }\Phi\cup\{\phi\}$ or $\text{Sat }\Phi\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ should hold. I got this absurd consequence while thinking about how independence from given set of formulas should be proved. Above statement is derived from the following two elemetary propositions :

1. $\Phi \models \phi \text{ iff not Sat } \Phi \cup \{\neg\phi\}$
2. $ \Phi \models \neg\phi \text{ iff not Sat } \Phi \cup \{\phi\} $

and thus directly follows from definition of independence and completeness, which is, if I know right, "$\phi$ is independent of $\Phi$ iff $\Phi \vdash \phi$ nor $\Phi \vdash \neg\phi$ holds".

It's a shame I can't come up with flaw myself in such short, elementary argument but would someone point out where it is that I have gone wrong.

Comment: Is Sat the statement that the theory is satisfiable (has a model, admits a validating valuation)? If so, your definition of independence is flawed. Instead, it should be that both $\Phi\cup\{\phi\}$ and $\Phi\cup\{\lnot\phi\}$ *are* satisfiable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh I get now what I got wrong. I got confused over few negations